# NSAttributedString.draw is very slow

Tags: ios, swift

```
let stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted()

if text.length != 0 {
    text.draw(with: textRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
}

print("stopwatch \(stopwatch.stop().toString())")
```

Results:

```
stopwatch 0.0241029262542725 s
stopwatch 0.0221379995346069 s
stopwatch 0.00433492660522461 s
stopwatch 0.00229907035827637 s
stopwatch 0.00661897659301758 s
stopwatch 0.00540506839752197 s
stopwatch 0.0047069787979126 s
stopwatch 0.00523698329925537 s
stopwatch 0.0541820526123047 s
```

The `text.draw` took up to 50 ms.
Is there a way to optimize the performance of `NSAttributedString.draw`?

This is the example of the `NSAttributedString`.

[image]

Comment: Why are you manually calling draw? Which function is this in? This is why you should generally use `drawRect`, since it's only called when the view needs to be redrawn and therefore ensuring good performance.

Comment: By which I mean that these `draw` methods should go in `drawRect`, so it's still ok to call it, but it needs to be done inside a `drawRect` method.

Comment: Of course it's in the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`. Where else can it be? I'm using custom draw to avoid jerky scrolling of the `UITableView`. So it must be redrawing after the cell is reused.

Comment: I just found a workaround. The `string.draw` will became slowly when the string size is huge. So we just need to split the string into several short paragraphs, each one contains no more than 50 chars.